# Trace view tables/columns back to system table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to get info on where system Views tables/columns get info from the system tables. Is there a way to find out where the view table/columns come from what system table? i have this sql to get the view table and column info. When i try to get the system table info i get back a ton of data which is close but to much info. Any help would be appreciated. I have looked around and there are some questions that are close to this but have not found something that helped.

--This gets the view table/columns info

```
SELECT 
    A.NAME AS 'VIEW_TABLE_NAME'
    , D.NAME AS 'VIEW_COLUMN_NAME'
    , CASE WHEN D.IS_NULLABLE = 0 THEN 'NO' ELSE 'YES' END AS NULLABLE
FROM 
    SYS.VIEWS A
LEFT JOIN 
    SYS.SCHEMAS C ON A.SCHEMA_ID = C.SCHEMA_ID
LEFT JOIN 
    SYS.COLUMNS D ON D.OBJECT_ID = A.OBJECT_ID
WHERE
    A.NAME LIKE 'QL%'
ORDER BY 
    A.NAME, D.NAME, D.IS_NULLABLE
```

When I added in system Table I get back too much info.

```
SELECT 
    A.NAME AS 'VIEW_TABLE_NAME', D.NAME AS 'VIEW_COLUMN_NAME'
    , CASE WHEN D.IS_NULLABLE = 0 THEN 'NO' ELSE 'YES' END AS NULLABLE
    , T.NAME AS 'TABLE_NAME'
FROM 
    SYS.TABLES T
LEFT JOIN 
    SYS.VIEWS A ON A.SCHEMA_ID = T.SCHEMA_ID
LEFT JOIN 
    SYS.SCHEMAS C ON A.SCHEMA_ID = C.SCHEMA_ID
LEFT JOIN 
    SYS.COLUMNS D ON D.OBJECT_ID = A.OBJECT_ID --AND D.OBJECT_ID = T.OBJECT_ID
WHERE
    A.NAME LIKE 'QL%'
GROUP BY 
    A.NAME, D.NAME, D.IS_NULLABLE, T.NAME 
ORDER BY 
    A.NAME
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: like here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms190624.aspx?

Comment: @marc_s - thanks for the reply. i tried what it said but and i did not get info that i was looking for. I tried what it said to do in sql statement in example. It did not work. i dont get the option for reference_id. Not sure how to get that out of the sql i have above. Any ideas on how to add that into code above?